# Arduino Uno as VGA to HDMI converter

Tags: arduino, converters, arduino-uno, hdmi, vga

Is it possible to make VGA (+3.5mm audio jack) to HDMI converter using Arduino Uno?

I would like to use TV as second monitor for my laptop but TV has only HDMI and my laptop has only VGA output. There are a lot of converters but they are very expencive.

I searched the internet but I can't find any example in which people used Arduino Uno as converter.

Comment: It is worth noting that you can get a cheap VGA -> HDMI converter on Amazon or the likes for $17.99 or less (with free shipping), which is cheaper than an Arduino Uno.

Answer (score 3):

The Arduino Uno does not have the processing power or IO capabilities required to do so.

The Uno can not even generate an HDMI output without special hardware (see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67098/can-i-output-a-hdmi-signal-with-an-arduino)), let alone convert VGA to HDMI.

What you would really need is an FPGA board (or an actual VGA -> HDMI converter).